# How I can find matched records in different column using MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with one MySQL Query.
I have a table with folowing structure:

```
+------+------+------+
| c1   |  c2  |  c3  |
+------+------+------+
| AA   |  A-A |  11  | - row1
| B-B  |   BB |  12  | - row2
| A-A  |   AA |  13  | - row3
| BB   |  B-B |  14  | - row4
| CC   |  C-C |  15  | - row5
| CC   |  C-C |  16  | - row6
| DD   |  DDD |  17  | - row7
+------+------+------+
```

IF ( record in **c1** == record in **c2** ) -> lines match

IF ( record in **c1** == record in **c1** ) -> lines match

```
row1 match row3

row2 match row4

row5 match row6
```

How can I creating mysql query to show me matched rows ?

I apologize for my english.
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a cross product:

```
SELECT * FROM table t1, table t2 WHERE t1.c1=t2.c1 OR t1.c1=t2.c2
```

Answer (score -1):

If you join the table to itself, you can specify what conditions it should match on. Just give it two different aliases like this:

```
    SELECT table1.*, 
           table2.* 
      FROM nameoftable table1
INNER JOIN nameoftable table2
        ON (table1.c1 = table2.c2
           OR table1.c1 = table2.c1)
```

You may find that it complains because you will have the same column names from each table, in which case, you'll need to specify aliases for each column without using * (which is not best practice anyway because you may be getting back more data than you need, which is slower):

```
SELECT table1.c1 AS t1c1,
       table1.c2 AS t1c2,
       table1.c3 AS t1c3,
       table2.c1 AS t2c1,
       table2.c2 AS t2c2,
       table2.c3 AS t2c3
```